# Android NDK: Converting .jpg to .bmp file

Tags: android-ndk

Can anyone suggest how I can convert a .jpg to a .bmp file in Android NDK?

Answer (score 0):

Use [stb_image](http://nothings.org/stb_image.c) to read the jpeg into memory, then use [stb_image_write](http://nothings.org/stb/stb_image_write.h) to write it back as a bmp. Both are C code, with no dependencies on any other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android's built-in `libjpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do more things with images I would recommend you take a look at OpenCv.  They support various formats plus you can easily crop, resize and work with the image pixels very fast.

The decode times I seen with OpenCv with 1280x720 png was 12ms if that matters to you.

Very simple way to open image:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

http://www.pictureresize.org/online-images-converter.html

Comment: Thanks for the response yes i am trying to convert .jpg to .bmp image file through pro grammatically using the android-ndk.